# CGContext get Pixelated on UIScollview Zoom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, blur, cgcontext

I have a UIScrollView in which I have added lines and squares with CGContext. When I zoomed in then lines and squares also zoomed but I want the line with should be shame. If I am not clear enough, I am posting image to understand the problem.

[image]

My client wants only line should be large and all other things will be same size.

I have done it by reducing the width on lines and radius of end circle but they get blurred on zoom.

[image]

Any other way to get this done??